# Windows Batch file for copying not working

Tags: batch-file

I am using batch commands to copy all the subfolders and all the files inside that subfolders to my USB drive  but I am unable to copy anything . The only thing I am getting is the message on console screen which is
40 file(s)

The commands that I am using are written below :

```
@echo off
xcopy "C:\Users\Public\Tally.ERP9\Data" "G:\Data" /Y /F /l /s /E /t /H /i
pause >nul
```

I had tried searching google but unable to find a right solution . I request all the elite members of stackoverflow to please suggest a right solution . Sorry for my bad English . Thanks in advance .

Comment: I recommend you look at the output of `XCOPY /?`. The `/T` switch suppresses copying of files.

Answer (score 2):

You are using parameter `/T`:

```
/T           Creates directory structure, but does not copy files.
```

Check `xcopy /?` to see what each parameter does and use only the ones that you need. You are also using `/S` and `/E`, which have the opposite effects.

Answer (score 1):

The `/l` switch shows the files that *would* be copied, but does not copy the files. Remove the `/l` and the copy should take place as was listed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks respected members ,
With the suggestions given by you all , I have managed to copy the files by altering my previous command to following one below .

```
@echo off
xcopy "C:\Users\Public\Tally.ERP9\Data" "G:\Data" /Y /Q /S /E /H /I
pause >nul
```